# Смена диска MS-DOS

Tags: linux, dos

У меня на компе стоит linux, то есть на диски он не разбит, всмысле c,d и т.д.
Запускаю с диска MS-DOS, по умолчанию конечно A:>

Как мне сохранять редактировать файлы или хотяб просмотреть их в директории компьютера?

Comment: проблема непонятна, чего-бы с линукса не редактировать файлы ?

Comment: (-) за грубость

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это MS-DOS версии < 4 то там был строчный редактор edlin, если версия типа >=4 то есть полноэкранный редактор EDIT.

Comment: ну я это знаю, когда нажимаю Save или Save As, то есть только диски A,R,B, но это на самом деле один диск - загрузочный

Comment: как получить доступ к корню системы

Comment: ох, боюсь никак. Под линуксом с большой вероятностью файловая система ext2/ext3, а у доса с ней проблемы:) он не знает ее, если не поставить драйвером. Хотите редактировать файлы - лучше скачайте маленький дистрибутив линуска, запишите на флешку или live cd и редактируйте.

Answer (score 0):

если нужно из-под линукса пускать досовские программы, то для этой цели давно уже существует DOSBox
то, что вы не видите привычных - С, Д, Е, - то это не значит, что их там нет :) разделы в линуксе именуются иначе и привязываются к папкам. Обычно такая разбивка-привязка осуществляется на этапе установки ОС, но можно и позже переразбить.
Все ваши творения сохраняйте в папке /home/user

Comment: @deivan

      то, что вы не видите привычных - С, Д, Е, - то это не значит, что их там нет :)

Нет, это как раз значит, что этой дури там нет. Лет -надцать назад зашёл на digicrime.com. Он предупредил -- проведёшь мышкой над этой ссылкой -- попорчу раздел C:. И как же бедный netscape пытался найти C: на винчестере...

Comment: мне сложно представить, что вы имеете ввиду под дурью, но я имел ввиду разделы на диске, которые в никсах именуются несколько иначе, чем заглавные одиночные буквы из начала латинского алфавита

Comment: Вот обозначение разделов заглавными буквами я и называю дурью. И эти буквы могут меняться, могут (в дискманагере) фиксироваться, и получается полный бардак

(А уж про net use и subst вообще лучше не вспоминать)

Comment: @Семен Савенко Шибко информативный комментарий. Но они не яснее вопроса "стоит linux, но на диски он не разбит". (Если запустить fdisk, линуксовый, то вряд ли, хотя и возможно, Вы увидите меньше двух разделов: ext2/ext3 и swap). Если нужен драйвер для чтения из-под доса этих разделов, то так и надо спрашивать (например http://www.askvg.com/how-to-access-linux-partitions-ext2-ext3-from-windows-in-dual-boot-system/, правда там винды).

Но звучит это примерно как вопрос на автозаправке: "А где же сено-то?"